# How to not throw a generically specified exception?

Tags: java, generics, exception, type-conversion, throwable

I created a "producer" interface (to be used with method references, respectively to be easily mocked for unit tests):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Factory<R, T, X extends Throwable> {
    public R newInstanceFor(T t) throws X;
}
```

which I created like that, as my first use case actually had to throw some checked `WhateverException`.

But my second use case doesn't have an X to throw.

The best I could come up with to make the compiler happy is:

```
Factory<SomeResultClass, SomeParameterClass, RuntimeException> factory;
```

That compiles, and does what I need, but still ugly. Is there a way to keep that single interface, but not provide an X when declaring specific instances?

Comment: Why is X part of the interface?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You would need something like a c++ template specialization.

Comment: @TimCastelijns looks like sneaky throws idiom...

Comment: What's wrong with `Factory<SomeResultClass, SomeParameterClass, ?>`?

Comment: @daniu, then `<?>` is a `Throwable` and is treated as such by compiler, forcing you to make a try-catch block.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Correct. Too bad.

Comment: @GhostCat, (not an answer, just comment on style) in your original code, consider doing what JDK does, and specify type parameters for input first, and then for output. Look at `java.util.function.Function<T,R>`, which is a `P1 => P2` function, not `P2 => P1` like yours.

Comment: as a side note, can you change your interface to `@FunctionalInterface
    public interface Factory<R, T> {
        R newInstanceFor(T t) throws Throwable;
    }`?

Comment: @Eugene That works for the "declaration" part, and passing a method reference. But actual invocations then give me "throws Throwable".

Comment: ah! indeed, sorry I can't let this one go... still thinking on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to do it is subclassing - but I bet you knew that. To make my argument stronger, look at `BinaryOperator` that extends `BiFunction`.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot do that in Java. The only way is to create a sub interface.

```
public interface DefaultExceptionFactory<R, T>
        extends Factory<R, T, RuntimeException>
```

Comment: @Eugene, I don't know if he needs to never spell out the type is the thing. He can make a wrapper method and place guarantees on it that the lambda in its argument never throws. Then he can spell out the `X` as an `AssertionError` (for cases when input lambda doesn't follow the contract). But that still needs a spell-out of the type in the use site.

Comment: you could also provide a wrapper implementation that upgrades any `Factory<R, T, ? extends RuntimeException>` to a `DefaultExceptionFactory<R, T>`

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a "social engineering" answer: we place a contract on the lambda form that it doesn't throw anything:

```
public interface Factory<T, R, X> {

    public R newInstanceFor(T arg) throws X;

    public static Factory<R, U, AssertionError> neverThrows(Factory<U, V, ?> input) {
        return u -> {
            try {
                return input.newInstanceFor(u);
            }
            catch(Throwable t) {
                throw new AssertionError("Broken contract: exception thrown", t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Usage is like this, or something along the lines of:

```
class MyClass {
    Factory<MyInput, MyOtherClass, AssertionError> factory;

    MyClass(Factory<MyInput, MyOtherClass, ?> factory) {
        this.factory = Factory.neverThrows(factory);
    }

    public void do() {
      factory.newInstanceFor(new MyInput()).do();
    }
}
```

Downside of this approach: you can't really specify the contract in the type signature, the contract is then an implementation detail. If you want to have this in type signature, you will need a second sub-interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the method as generic like below code, if it is possible for you:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Factory<R, T> {
    public <X extends Throwable> R newInstanceFor(T t) throws X;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but I haven't managed to get that compiled. Have you tried making instances that throw, say, `IOException`?

Comment: It compiles for me, but unfortunately, it breaks my first usecase. When using references like `SomeClassThatReallyThrows::new` ... now asks to handle that exception "really thrown". Too bad, this looked really nice.

Comment: More specifically, I'm receiving compile errors for use site of this lambda form saying "`Illegal lambda expression: Method newInstanceFor of type Fiddle.Factory<String,String> is generic`".

Comment: @GhostCat, the lambda SAM type itself does compile for me as well. The use sites don't though.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov to making instance you must specify exception like `instance.<ExceptionType>newInstanceFor(parameter);`  or let java to recognize itself see the https://github.com/jsunsoftware/concurrent/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jsunsoft/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.java

Comment: @BenoArakelyan, I don't understand how this example fits, to be honest. You have concrete classes, while this question is more about functional interfaces. I haven't managed to compile a sample using your code when I implement `Factory` with lambda expression. If you have an example, please add it to your answer.

Comment: @GhostCat I don't understand why the instantation of  SomeClassThatReallyThrows should ask you to handle exception?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You can't use it explicitly as lambda. Java doesn't support that. I have added the link for show how you can construct generic flexible API with lambda. You can pay attention toward the Lock and Executable classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177097/discussion-between-beno-arakelyan-and-m-prokhorov).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Project Lombok**'s [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) annotation:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Factory<R, T> {

    @SneakyThrows
    R newInstanceFor(T t);
}
```

This allows you to throw any exception (checked or unchecked). But read the documentation because this feature must be handled with care.

Comment: this sneaky throws feature is not lombok specific, but rather jls specific. And have you tried your code againt OPs requirments?

Answer (score -3):

Do you have to make the exception generic? Why not define the interface as

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Factory<R, T> {
    public R newInstanceFor(T t) throws Throwable;
}
```

You can always catch your exception and check the type if you need in your calling function.

Comment: Exception as type parameter limits implementing code in the types of exception it can throw.

Comment: True that. But in this case, the exception type is 'X extends Throwable.'

Comment: Yes, but actual code which uses the `Factory` can say `accept(Factory<R, T, ? extends IOException> factory)`.

Comment: Ahh, missed that. Agreed. Thanks.