# Create exception safe execution wrapper in Java

Tags: java, android, error-handling, exception

I have a lot of code with `try`/`catch` and in almost all cases I take the same action. What I want to do is simplify my error handling by creating something where I can just say

```
ManagedExceptionEnvironment() {
    // The code that might throw exceptions
}
```

And then inside of `ManagedExceptionEnvironment` it has the shared error handling logic.

My initial thought on this was to have `ManagedExceptionEnvironment`'s constructor take a `Runnable`, but if you put logic that might throw an exception inside an anonymous `Runnable`'s `run` method then it still complains about not implementing `try`/`catch` even if the container you're passing it to would have taken care of it.

I suppose another option is to only handle the errors at the highest level and have them keep getting thrown up another level, though that seems rather risky.

Edit: I guess one option here (and I don't know if this is a thing in Java) is some kind of macro?

Edit 2: Just did some cursory reading on using the C pre-processor to inject macros into Java src and that is really horrifying. So macros are out as a solution.

Comment: Lambda expressions are available for [every version of Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: @CommonsWare so to get this straight, all versions of android support lambdas but not all other features of Java 8?

Comment: It's a mixed bag. The big thing is that Java 8 *classes* are not available prior to API Level 24. Lambda expressions do not involve Java 8 classes. The Android toolchain generates compiled code for lambda expressions that can run on any version of Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `ManagedExceptionEnvironment` was going to extend some existing class, there is no value in using a Java class here as opposed to a `static` method. So, you could write:

```
public static <T> T boomProtector(Callable<T> thingThatMightGoBoom) {
  try {
    return thingThatMightGoBoom.call();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    // TODO: your standard catch logic
  }

  return null;
}
```

Then, where you need it, you can call:

```
Whatever result = boomProtector(() -> earthShatteringKaboom());
```

where `Whatever` is the type that `earthShatteringKaboom()` returns. If `earthShatteringKaboom()` returns an object, you get it in `result`. If it throws an exception, your standard catch logic is executed and `result` is `null`.

(note: I am showing Java 8 syntax for the sample `boomProtector()` call, which you will need to enable in your project, such as via File > Project Settings > app in Android Studio — or, use an anonymous inner class implementation of `Callable<T>`)

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping it in an interface like this:

```
class ManagedExceptionEnvironment {
    public static void safeExecution(Wrapper w) {
        try {
            w.codeThatThrows();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // your error handling
        }
    }


    public static void example() {
        safeExecution(() -> { throw new Exception(); });
        // Or the old-fashioned way:
        safeExecution(new Wrapper() {
            @Override
            public void codeThatThrows() throws Exception {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        });
    }

    interface Wrapper {
        public void codeThatThrows() throws Exception;
    }
}
```

The trick is that the method that is analogous to `Runnable.run()` specifies that it may throw an Exception whereas `run()` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can make exceptions part of the (generic) signature of your interface / class / method. See my question ( [How to not throw a generically specified exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612250/how-to-not-throw-a-generically-specified-exception) ) as example.

Instead of calling the method "newInstance()" you could name it "process()" for example. And then create a type safe handler around that. And clients simply pass lambda expressions around.

Basically defining your own wrapper (as shown in the other answer :-)